# Looking for an alternative in POSTGRESQL which give windows login username

Tags: postgresql, settings, database-administration

We need an alternative for oracle function Sys_context('USERENV', 'OS_USER'),which gives Windows username. How to achieve in PostgreSQL. I was able to get only username related to database and not windows login.
Any help would be appreciated.

Below commands tried out gives db username. Looking forward for Windows login username

```
SELECT usename FROM pg_user; 

select user

SELECT d.datname as "Name",pg_catalog.pg_get_userbyid(d.datdba) as "Owner"
FROM pg_catalog.pg_database d
WHERE d.datname = 'database_name'
ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: There is no way to obtain that name in Postgres. But that was a very insecure thing to do in Oracle to begin with. The value for `os_user` is provided by the client in Oracle and is **not** a safe way to detect that user. I can make that contain `dpsg` , `Larry Ellison` or `Zaphod Beeblebrox` if I want to (regardless of my OS user).

Comment: That sounds like a [X-Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377). What underlying problem are you trying to solve with that information?

Comment: Basically i want to capture which user has done a particular action,as the database user remains the same..how can we achieve this?